# Given a positive definite matrix $B$ , $B\geq \underline{b}I$, $AA^T$ is positive semi-definite. Can $ABA^T\geq b AA^T$?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Given matrix $B$ is positive definite, and $B\geq \underline{b}I$,  $AA^T$ is positive semi-definite. Can the following inequality hold? $$ABA^T\geq  \underline{b}AA^T.$$

Comment: Is $b=\underline b$?

Comment: Yes, I fix it. Thx

Comment: Check $ABA^T - \underline b AA^T$. Is it positive semidefinite?

Comment: Matrices are unknown

Comment: You know that $B-\underline b I$ is positive definite. Can you spot that matrix?

Comment: @user251257 yeah, do you mean the inequality holds?

Comment: Yes, it does. ${}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
x^TABA^Tx = (A^Tx)^TB(A^Tx)\ge b(A^Tx)^T(A^Tx) = x^T(bAA^T)x.
$$